# Unit norm eigenvector of a pair of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a research paper where it says "Let $\mathbf{d_j}$ be the unit norm eigenvector of $(\mathbf{R_j, Q_j})$ corresponding to the largest eigenvector". How is this $\mathbf{d_j}$ calculated? Is this the largest common eigenvector between the two matrices?

Note: $\mathbf{R_j, Q_j}$ are same-sized symmetric (square) matrices.

The paper is linked below:
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=513557

The sentence is taken from below eqn. (24) in the paper.

Comment: I suppose ".. corresponding to the largest eigenvalue"? -- What are $R_j$, $Q_j$? Same-size square matrices?

Comment: Can you link the paper?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It says "corresponding to the largest eigenvector". Could it be that they mean the largest eigenvector of the concatenated matrix?

Comment: @ALB I just did.

Comment: I guess it is a generalized eigenvector...? Btw. not everyone  has a ieee account. You should just quote it.

Comment: @user251257 Isn't generalized eigenvector definied for one matrix only?

Comment: @Teodorism sorry for the ambiguous wording. I meant a solution to the generalized eigenvalue problem like $(A-\lambda B)v = 0$.